# Is it possible to make a CMS which controls the Subdomains of a Site

Tags: php, content-management-system, admin

Maybe this question sounds silly or weird to you, but it runs into my head for days so I decided to ask it here.

Basically I'm making a Custom Management System with PHP and because my Website contains a lot of Subdomains, I just wanted to know that is it possible to Manage them within one Admin Control Panel ?

Let's say my Sites looks like this:

- www.mysite.com (site 1)
- www.subdomain1.mysite.com (site 2)
- www.subdomain2.mysite.com (site 3)

And my CMS will be uploaded to the root directory:

- www.mysite.com/admin

So from this panel, I have to be able to insert, delete and edit blog posts, images and etc.

So is this possible or I just wasting my time on that ?

Comment: Very very possible. What have you tried

Comment: You might want to edit your question and tag which technologies you want to use. (I have assumed PHP and Apache in my answer but I will edit if you tag it with something different)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The usual approach is to make your Apache config contain a wildcard match that sends all requests to your application:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example_application/public_html
  ServerName  www.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And then in the sites code simply grab the subdomain:

```
$parts = explode( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.');
$subdomain = $parts[0];
// A db query to check if this subdomain is valid
// Either set the channel or return 404
```

Comment: @ciomaejobaep Did my solution answer your question?